# Sharp constant in the $L^p$ regularity estimate?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, laplacian, poissons-equation

**Problem**: Let us denote $\mathbb{W}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ the space of Sobolev functions in the plane. Let us denote with $\Delta$ the classic Laplacian operator. We know that there exists a constant $C>0$, depending only on $p$ and $d$, such that if $f \in \mathbb{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $u \in \mathbb{W}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and:
$$
-\Delta u = f
$$
in the weak sense, then it holds:
$$
\|\partial_i \partial_j u \|_{\mathbb{L}^{p}(\mathbb{R}^2)} \leq C \|f \|_{\mathbb{W}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^2)} \quad \text{ for all } i,j \in \{1,2\}
$$
I want to find the sharp constant $C$ with this property. In other words I want to find the least possible constant $C$ such that the property above holds.

**Attempt:** I tried using Fourier theory and the Hardy–Littlewood–Sobolev theorem but this does not work if $\alpha=2$ is equal to the dimension $d=2$, where $\alpha$ is the power associated to the $\Delta$ operator seen as a Fourier multiplier.

Any help or any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: It is a very difficult problem, and I am not sure it is known. Notice that this correspond to ask the norm of the operator $T = (-\Delta)^{-1}\partial_i\partial_j$ as an operator on $L^p$. This operator can be written $T=R_iR_j$ where $R$ is the Hilbert transform (the operator with symbol $x/|x|$). Optimal constant are known for this operator in certain cases, such as the $1d$ case (https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/mrl/content/vols/0004/0004/a003) where the answer is $\tan(\pi/(2p))$ if $p\in(1,2]$, and $\cot(\pi/(2p))$ if $p\in[2,\infty)$ ...

Comment: I had looked some time ago and I think I had found other results (perhaps multidimensional as well?). At least there is a torus version here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123600936164

Comment: I think you meant to write the $L^p$ norm on the right-hand side, not the $W^{2,p}$ one. Here, I must agree with LL pi: this problem seems quite difficult.